# Reading hexadecimal output from a pointer location in C while it ends

Tags: c, pointers

I have an unsigned char pointer which points to a N bytes of length, hexadecimal plain text data.

I don't know the length of the data.

How do I read it while it ends? As there might be zero-bytes in the data, I'm not sure how it is possible to mark the end of the data.

Comment: If it's "plain text" (i.e. a *string*) then remember that strings in C are really called ***null-terminated** byte strings*.

Comment: Please show the code of how this hexadecimal is declared and what you have coded up to now.

Comment: "How do I read it while it ends?"  Since it points to `N` bytes, that is the length.

Comment: If all you have is a pointer *and* your byte sequence may contain 0s as part of the data *and* you don’t have a unique byte sequence to mark the end of the data (such as `0xFFFFFFFF` or `0xDEADBEEF`), then you’re basically screwed.  You really need a way to specify the length explicitly, either by encoding it in the first few bytes of the stream, or providing it as a separate argument.

Comment: Please what exactly do you consider "*hexadecimal plain text data*"?

Comment: Well anything pretty much, alk. Byte after byte.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, char pointers point to a C string, which is a null terminated string. That means that the last character is a null byte, or `'\0'` in C. If this is correct then you can write a loop and read chars until you reach a char that is equal to `'\0'`. If there are zero bytes the first byte will be `'\0'`.

Comment: This does not answer the question: Where is the end of the complete data? Following your assumption the question would be: How to know which is the last string?